# passing a list to subprocess.check_output

Tags: python, subprocess

```
argument_list = ['name=Jon', 'id=100' ]

output = subprocess.check_output(
         ['/usr/bin/python', 'test.py', argument_list ], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

In simple terms, I am trying to invoke a script using subprocess called test.py; I want to pass arguments to test.py through a list. Importatnt - List can be of any size.

Things I tried ,

```
output = subprocess.check_output(
         ['/usr/bin/python', 'test.py', ", ".join(argument_list) ], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

and

```
output = subprocess.check_output(
         ['/usr/bin/python', 'test.py', '%s' % argument_list ], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Neither works because in subprocess.checkoutput should be  (' ', ' ' ,' ') etc....

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a new list by adding lists together:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/python', 'test.py'] + argument_list, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

This will run `test.py` with `argument_list` as it's command-line parameters.

Comment: This is awesome. Wouldn't have crossed this hurdle without your help. Thanks!